# How does UIKit know which view should accept touch events?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiresponder

I have a button view that displays a popup view when touched. The popup view overlaps the button completely, but all `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` events are still routed to the button view. What if I want to handle touches in the popup view? I know I can simply delegate touch events from the button to the popup view by hand, but is there a better solution?

Comment: How are you adding to popup view?

Comment: I’m adding it to the button’s superview.

Comment: i have did same thing recently

Comment: use this one https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/